# Excel Application WindowState not behaving (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

The code I typically use in VBA to minimize and run processes in the background is:

```
 With Excel.Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .Calculation = Excel.xlCalculationManual
    .EnableEvents = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .WindowState = xlMinimized
 End With
```

For some reason the application window keeps alternatively restoring and minimizing when the code runs, instead of staying minimized. I think it has to do with either the data refresh or copying data to a text file processes. Of course I want to keep it running minimized in the background. I do not want to hide the application.  Here is the code I think is causing the problem:

```
Sub StockUpdate()
'
' Rainmeter File Macro
'
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim saveFile As String
Dim WorkRng As Range
'
With Excel.Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .Calculation = Excel.xlCalculationManual
    .EnableEvents = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .WindowState = xlMinimized
End With
Calculate
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
Calculate
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
Sheets("Main").Activate
Range("C16:C25").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("C27:C36").Activate
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("C27:C36").Select
Selection.Copy
Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Add
wb.Worksheets(1).Paste
wb.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "[filepath]\Test.txt", FileFormat:= _
        xlText, CreateBackup:=False
wb.Close
Application.CutCopyMode = False
If On_Timer = 1 Then Call Duration
End Sub
```

The data refresh part is an external web query that is set to run in the background, and the above code is a subroutine so the Excel.Application changes made at the top are reset elsewhere.  I appreciate any advice. thanks

Answer (score 0):

try something like :

```
application.windows(thisworkbook.name).windowstate = xlMinimized
```

you can only select things you can see, so of course the window will popup again, instead avoid using select and activate and format your code like :

```
Sheets("Main").Range("C27:C36").value = Sheets("Main").Range("C16:C25").value
Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Add
windows(wb.name).windowstate=xlminimized
thisworkbook.sheets("Main").Range("C27:C36").copy wb.sheets(1)
wb.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "[filepath]\Test.txt", FileFormat:= _
    xlText, CreateBackup:=False
wb.Close savechanges:=False
```

Comment: just for those who search for the literal value of xlMinimized constant, it is -4140 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834884.aspx